# Llamar datos de una Base de Datos Firebase para Validar

Tags: javascript, html, json, nodejs, firebase

Tengo un formulario simple en HTML en donde hay 3 inputs de tipo texto, uno llamado "Dia" otro llamado "Mes y otro "Anio (Año)" , y este mismo en una variable llamada "Fecha" hace lo siguiente:

```
var fecha = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + anio
```

Y el resultado sería algo tipo: `26/05/2021`, necesito validar que a la hora que alguien ingrese nuevamente esta fecha y una hora `(Ejemplo: 08:30 pm)` de un error tipo

> "Esta cita ya existe, por favor, verifique una disponible"

El código que estoy probando es:

```
else if (fecha == db.collection("citas_registradas").fecha && hora == db.collection("citas_registradas").hora) {
        alert('Esta cita ya existe, por favor, verifique una disponible.');
```

`fecha` es el nombre de mi campo en mi base de datos de firebase, y "`citas_registradas`" mi tabla, ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer esa validación? , les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que la "hora" el usuario la ingresa en un cuarto input. Y que en el objeto `fecha_input` guardamos en su propiedad `fecha_input.date` la fecha y en `fecha_input.hora` la hora ingresada.

En la base de datos guardamos todos esos datos en un objeto llamado `fecha` dentro de un documento de `Firebase` de la siguiente manera:

```
let fecha = {
  date: fecha_input.date,
  hora: fecha_input.hora    
}
```

La próxima vez que un usuario vuelva a registrar una cita, lo que hay que hacer ahora es validar si ya existen esos datos en la base de datos.

Para hacer esa validación, podrías hacer una consulta `.get()` y usar la condición `.where()`.

Por ejemplo:

```
let fechaExiste
 
db.collection("citas_registradas").where("fecha.date", "==", 
fecha_input.date).where("fecha.hora", "==", fecha_input.hora)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        fechaExiste = doc.data()
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

En este ejemplo estaríamos accediendo a los datos de la colección `citas_registradas` y buscando todos los documentos cuyo valor `fecha.date` y `fecha.hora` sean iguales a la fecha y hora que acaban de ingresar en los inputs, que en este caso estarían en el objeto llamado `fecha_input`.

El resultado de esa consulta la guardaremos en el objeto `fechaExiste`.

Luego hacemos una validación con un `if`:

```
if (fechaExiste) {
    alert('Esta cita ya existe, por favor, verifique una disponible.');
}
```

De esta manera, si hay datos encontrados en el objeto `fechaExiste` comunicamos al usuario el mensaje.

En esta documentación hay más información sobre este tipo de consultas a `Firebase`:

[Obtén varios documentos de una colección](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero en este caso si necesito que se repitan las fechas, ya que hoy, 02/04/2021 hay varias citas, una a las 9:30 am, otra a las 10:30 am, etc, lo que debe de hacer es que cuando 02/04/2021 y 9:30 am ya existan (VALIDAR AMBAS), de el error si intentan registrar la misma fecha y la misma hora.

Comment: Está bien, pero de todas formas mi respuesta se puede adaptar a lo que estás buscando. El dato que me faltaría sería saber de qué manera el usuario ingresa la "hora", ya que no especificaste eso en tu pregunta. Pero igual habría una manera de hacerlo. Ahora mismo edito mi respuesta para adaptarla a eso.

Answer (score 1):

Según la respuesta de mi amigo Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza, modifiqué su respuesta para adaptarla, no es necesario utilizar un constructor ni un objeto ni nada por el estilo, por lo que el código que me funcionó a mi sería el siguiente:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").where("fecha", "==", fecha).where("hora", "==", hora).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                fechaValidacion = fecha;
                horaValidacion = hora;
                }
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    if (fecha == fechaValidacion && hora == horaValidacion) {
        Swal.fire("Oops!", "Esa cita ya está llena, por favor, busque las citas libres y agende una.", "error");
    }
```

Sustituyendo el Swal.fire por Alert, ya que el Swal.Fire es un CDN para hacer los alerts más visuales, adjunto link: https://sweetalert2.github.io/